# how did you resolve installing solana-test-validator on a Mac M1 Max?

Tags: solana-test-validator, m1

How did you overcome the challenge of reaching `illegal hardware instruction solana-test-validator`?

I have installed Solana and Rust and Openssl.

Running `Solana --version` returns `solana-cli 1.13.2 (src:18fe44c1; feat:4011803773)`.

Running `rustup --version` returns `` rustup 1.25.1 (bb60b1e89 2022-07-12) info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler. info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19) ``.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into these solutions? These might help:

> [solana-test-validator: illegal hardware instruction](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/solana-test-validator-illegal-hardware-instruction)

> https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/17406