# solana-test-validator: illegal hardware instruction

Tags: validator, solana-cli, solana-test-validator, m1

Has anyone else experienced this error **illegal hardware instruction** when trying to run `solana-test-validator`? More specifically:

[image]

Im using M1 Macbook and having versions

- solana-test-validator 1.14.3 (src:fa1e3263; feat:940802714)
- rustup 1.25.1 (bb60b1e89 2022-07-12)
- OS X 12.3 M1 Pro

Is there a method that circumvents the use of the Rosetta Terminal? Since that is no longer necessary with the newer solana cli.

These are the test-ledger logs

```
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.280645000Z INFO  solana_test_validator] solana-validator 1.14.3 (src:fa1e3263; feat:940802714)
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.280737000Z INFO  solana_test_validator] Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
        ],
    }
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.280774000Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.288195000Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.288221000Z INFO  solana_faucet::faucet] Faucet account address: 37uumhpj41qru1WL6KwDMAV1E3g6r8xn1UkDSG56TKmL
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.292883000Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Maximum open file descriptors: 1000000
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.292911000Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening database at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
[2022-10-08T21:03:12.507174000Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] "test-ledger/rocksdb" open took 214ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Jon C.

I resolved it by downloading the aarch64 [Prebuilt Binaries](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#download-prebuilt-binaries).

Then I moved these binaries into the solana bin folder: /Users/USERNAME/.local/share/solana.

Although this requires that whenever you use a given solana binary for the first time, you need to open it and give it permission. I.e. open it with ctrl button.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to build the whole thing yourself if you don't want to use Rosetta.  Thankfully, this is pretty easy!  With Rust installed, just run:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v1.14.3 https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git
cd solana
./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .
echo "export PATH=$PWD/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

More information at https://dev.to/0xmuse/install-solana-on-m1-macs-without-rosetta-10m5

Answer (score 1):

Just checked my logs and it seems like you have a few missing components in logs like vote account and authorized voted that could have been the cause of error.

> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.928710000Z ^[[0m^[[33mWARN ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m identity: DHPHHqA98yQMie198x92aN6wYSS3AUoJcfZWDh3bQY2
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.928728000Z ^[[0m^[[33mWARN ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m vote account: Ds2hW3RHmveHeSv1YcP7nKjD6mTtyEcc4trmM1ZkGyYX
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.928898000Z ^[[0m^[[33mWARN ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m authorized voter: Ds2hW3RHmveHeSv1YcP7nKjD6mTtyEcc4trmM1ZkG$
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.928954000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m Initializing sigverify...
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.929007000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m Done.
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.929017000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m Cleaning accounts paths..
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.952199000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m done. clean_accounts_paths took 22ms
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.952395000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m Geyser plugin: accounts_update_notifier: false transaction_$
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.952551000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::system_monitor_service^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m Starting SystemMonitorService
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.952700000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m loading ledger from "test-ledger"...
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.955780000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_core::validator^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m genesis hash: 9JRkJvMfSjavvDpoh3Sc6gHFFj6P2aznLBunmjLtuE2U
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53:00.956204000Z ^[[0m^[[32mINFO ^[[0m solana_ledger::blockstore^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m Maximum open file descriptors: 500000
> ^[[0m^[[38;5;8m[^[[0m2022-10-09T04:53: